# Label color in today extension in iOS 13

Tags: swift, colors, label, ios13, today-extension

In a strange way, all labels in today's extension iOS 13 began to appear in black color. In all other versions, the correct color is displayed. Does anyone mean why?

**iOS 13:**

[image]

**iOS12:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it and yes, if i set the text color in storyboard i had the same effect (but on both ios version), but if i set the textcolor of label manually in code in NCWidgetProviding -> it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. At the moment, the only solution that I have found is to override the color of all `UILabel` programmatically. But this is not elegant ...